# How to get the byte counts parts of real type number defined in C using GMP

Tags: c, floating-point, gmp

I have inherited a project written in C which uses a real number type mapped onto a multiple precision floating-point number from the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP).

At run-time, to test the byte count for this real number type, I can run:

```
printf("Storage size for Real type: %d bytes\n", sizeof(Real));
```

Gives 24 bytes, i.e. 192 bits.

However, the file defining the class also has the following lines:

```
#define REAL_EPSILON 1e-24
#define REAL_FORMAT "% 25.24Fe"
#define REAL_IOTA 1e-96
#define REAL_PRECISION 128
```

Can anyone shed any light on these lines? I am especially concerned as to whether the last line indicates 128 bits, or 16 bytes, is given to the byte count for the decimal part of the number.

Comment: That means there's 16 bytes for the mantissa, but the `Real` structure also includes members for the exponent and sign, and maybe other things. Those are the other 8 bytes.

Comment: @Barnar: Let me make sure that I understand you: are you saying that I essentially correct in thinking that the 16 bytes are for the decimal?

Comment: Yes, I think so. If you want to be sure, check the source code and look at the structure declaration for `Real`.

Comment: That's the issue. In the project code, the Real type was defined by the project's writer and he is no longer available.

Comment: I thought you were getting this from the GMP library. Anyway, why do you need the author, don't you have the source code?

Comment: The Real type being used is only mapped to the float type in GMP.

Comment: In that case `sizeof(Real)` is the same as `sizeof(float)`, and I'm surprised it's 24 bytes.

Comment: That is the size given by the sizeOf function in my testing. It is a customisation to specifically allow large numbers of preceding zeroes in the mantissa.

Comment: Saw this thread while looking for a different solution. Got randomly curious about the source of this C code, and found https://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/site/assets/files/1025/farmer.pdf (edit: page 145).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind GMP, the GNU *Multiple* Precision Arithmetic Library, is that it can handle *multiple* (and very large) precisions. Therefore, a fixed size that `sizeof` can return for its floating-point data type doesn't make sense.

GMP numbers are implemented using a header struct, with one or more pointers to the actual data, where the actual number is stored. That can be very large numbers, stored with thousands or millions of bits.

`sizeof` is a built-in C operator, and it just gives the size of the header struct. This result just means that the header struct is 24 bytes. It does *not* have anything at all to do with precision or number of digits.

Comment: @MrMorgan: As in `mpf_set_default_prec(128);`? That will set the default precision to be (at least) 128 bits.

Comment: I need to check such an explicit instruction. What documentation there is states that a default 128 bit precision is used.

Comment: The code that calls GMP sets it. Read more here: https://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions